# "make money on something" or "make money out of something"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Tell me please which one of the following sentence sounds more natural.

> I am trying to **make money on** my hobby.
>
> I am trying to **make money out of** my hobby.

What I am trying to say is that I am using my hobby, teaching, as a means earning a living.
If any of the sentence isn't correct, then what is the correct way to say it?

Comment: I would say ***from*** *my hobby*, but this is subjective. (Making money ***on*** *my hobby* would only really make sense if my hobby involved gambling and placing bets—and even then it sounds a little strange to me.) Other possibilities are ***thanks to*** and ***because of***.

Comment: Either singular or plural *mean* should be **means**.